# Interning strings in Java

Tags: java, string, string-interning

The following segment of code interns a string.

```
String str1="my";
String str2="string";
String concat1=str1+str2;
concat1.intern();

System.out.println(concat1=="mystring");
```

The expression `concat1=="mystring"` returns `true` because `concat1` has been interned.

---

If the given string `mystring` is changed to `string` as shown in the following snippet.

```
String str11="str";
String str12="ing";
String concat11=str11+str12;
concat11.intern();

System.out.println(concat11=="string");
```

The comparison expression `concat11=="string"` returns `false`. The string held by `concat11` doesn't seem to be interned. What am I overlooking here?

I have tested on Java 7, update 11.

---

**EDIT:**

The whole code:

```
package test;

public final class Test
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        String str11="my";
        String str12="string";
        String concat11=str11+str12;
        concat11.intern();
        System.out.println(concat11=="mystring");

        String str1="str";
        String str2="ing";
        String concat1=str1+str2;
        concat1.intern();
        System.out.println(concat1=="string");
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the above does intern the strings, but you're tossing away the interned versions.  You must save the result from the intern function call if you intend to use it immediately.

Comment: `String.intern()` *returns* the interned version. It never changes the original string (i.e. `concat1`), since strings are immutable in Java. Either way, use `equals` for string comparison (unless you have very convincing reasons to use `intern`).

Comment: Can you clarify that when you see `concat11` returning false, you are running a program that includes both of these snippets?

Comment: The first example works because the string is *already* interned, since the compiler figured out it could combine str1 & str2 into a single literal.  Whether it does this or not depends on the context and cannot be relied upon in the general case.

Comment: I have commented out the code in one snippet but it always returns `false`, in case, the string taken is `string` and `true` otherwise.

Comment: Can you post your whole program then, so I can run it exactly as you have, and find what the problem is?

Comment: So the program that you just posted acts as you've described, does it?  What is the thing that doesn't work?

Comment: It returns `true`, if the assignment of the concatenation expression is other than `string` but it returns `false`, if it is `string` that should not happen. Why does this happen?

Comment: OK, I'm getting slightly different results from you, using Java 6.0 build 45.  I don't have Java 7 build 11 on the PC that I'm using now.  If you can wait several hours till I can get to my home machine, I will try again there.

Comment: You could try to use .equals() or .equalsIgnoreCase(), or if you are interested in how the pool works, then you might want to try switching your literals to be before your variables and see if you get a different response :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `intern()` on string that wasn't in string pool earlier this string will be placed there and every next literal will use reference to it.

But if there is already some literal in strings pool and you will try to invoke `intern()` on newly created string object with same characters, it will not be placed in pool but will only return reference to string from pool. Also it will not change reference to original string on which `intern` was invoked.

Since Java loads and executes some code before executing `main` method there is a chance that some literals will be placed in string pool before execution of `main` code.
For example String pool will contain literals such as `"UTF-8"`, `"charset"`, `"charsetName"`, which may come from `java.lang.String`, or `java.nio.charset.Charset` classes. It seems that `"string"` literal is one of them (I am not sure where exactly it was added to String pool).

So when you are invoking

```
String str11="str";
String str12="ing";
String concat11=str11+str12;
concat11.intern();
```

your `intern` will not put `"string"` from `concat11` in string pool because there is one already there and other `"string"` literals (like these you used in `=="string"` part) will be using the one from string pool, not from `concat11`.

Lets test this theory:

```
String s = "ABCdef";// this string will be placed in 
                    // string pool before rest of code

String str1 = "ABC";
String str2 = "def";
String concat1 = str1 + str2;
concat1.intern();//this will only return reference to literal from pool

System.out.println(concat1 == "ABCdef");//false


// here we don't have any "ABcd" literal in pool yet
String strA = "AB";
String strB = "cd";
String concatAB = strA + strB;
concatAB.intern();//so this will put String object from concatAB to pool
System.out.println(concatAB == "ABcd");//and "ABcd" literal will use same object
```

output

```
false
true
```

Comment: "*String pool will contain literals such as `UTF-8`, `charset`, `charsetName`, which may come from `java.lang.String`, or `java.nio.charset.Charset` classes. It seems that `string` literal is one of them*". If this is really the case then, this is the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Tiny actually such literals can appear in many standard classes so I am not sure if they come from these ones. But since we don't really know how exactly Java creates String object for String literals like which constructor it uses and what methods are invoked next I assume that this literals may come from code in `String` class.

Answer (score 6):

If you run both of these snippets in the same program, then `concat1.intern()` will add `concat1` to the pool of interned strings.  But `concat11.intern()` won't add anything to the pool, because `"string"` is already in the pool (from `str2`).  So your last comparison is comparing `concat11` to `str2` - and these are not the same object.

From the Javadoc at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/String.html

> When the intern method is invoked, if the pool already contains a string equal to this String object as determined by the equals(Object) method, then the string from the pool is returned. Otherwise, this String object is added to the pool and a reference to this String object is returned.

Comment: I have commented out the code in one snippet but it always returns `false`, in case, the string taken is `string` and `true` otherwise (if the string is other than `string`). Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: One question. Lets run only code from first example. If we remove `concat1.intern();` result will be `false`, but if we let it stay result will be `true`. But in other code example where concatenation would return `"string"` commenting `concat11.intern();` will not matter and result will always be `false`. Why?

Comment: `concat11.intern()` doesn't change the pool, because `"string"` is already there.  So commenting it out changes nothing.

Answer (score 2):

When a string is created and if the string already exists in the pool, the reference of the existing string will be returned, instead of creating a new object and returning its reference.

refer this site http://java.dzone.com/articles/why-string-immutable-java